# Positive semi-definiteness of $\sum_i \alpha_i x_ix_i^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Assume that we have $N$ column vectors $x_i; \ i=1,\ldots, N$, and $N$ real numbers $\alpha_i; \ i=1,\ldots,N$.

Can we write down a necessary condition for $\alpha_i$'s under which $\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i x_ix_i^T$ is positive semi-definite?

(A sufficient condition would be $\alpha_i\geq 0$, but I want a necessary condition.)

Comment: hmmm, i didn't read your question correctly..... you have N vectors $ x_i \in R^n$  how is PSD defined for that, i know PSD for matrices

Comment: $x_ix_i^T$ is a matrix.

Comment: ok,ok $A=\sum_i \alpha_i x_i x_i^T$ then $y^TAy=\sum_i \alpha_i y^T x_i x_i^T y =\sum_i \alpha_i y^T x_i( y^T x_i )^T = \sum_i \alpha_i (y^T x_i)^2 $ because $ y^T x_i$ is a number, and if $x_i$ can be whatever , you chose some negative alpha, and if there are positive $\alpha_i$ you use $x_i=(0,0,....0)^T$ (in sum it's $\alpha_i \cdot 0 $), then your matrix(not sum, noob me) is not positive definite

Comment: If $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ are linearly independent, then the nonnegativity of $\alpha$'s is also necessary.